# Perform distinct count over 5 measures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powerpivot, slicers

I need to use TSQL to write a query on SSMS 2012 that calculates a distinct count of the charge_log_date per measure.  This charge_log_date field is a smalldatetime (the hour is stored as "00:00:00"), so only the day count matters.

This dataset will be used to populate a PowerPivot table with 5 slicers total, one per measure.  These measures are titled:

```
payor_family, company_name, base_type, base_state, payor_code
```

When the user clicks on any of these slicers, this charge_log_day_count needs to count the distinct # of days/measure clicked.  So if they only click one payor_family and no other slicers, the dataset needs to include counts for that payor_family only.  This is the simple case.  But if they click on more than one slicer, the dataset needs to include the counts for each slicer measure selected.

What I did so far was to create a lookup table that stores the counts for each of these 5 measures, with one measure value per row, where NULLS represent the other values.

**ASK:**
 How can I join this table to the main dataset to only include the relevant counts?  Here is a sample table with data:

```
create table #charge_log_dates 
(
payor_family varchar(5),
 company_name varchar(5),
 base_type varchar(5), 
base_state varchar(5), 
payor_code varchar(5), 
ct int
)

insert #charge_log_dates values('PF1',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,5)
insert #charge_log_dates values('PF2',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,10)
insert #charge_log_dates values('PF3',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,25)
insert #charge_log_dates values(NULL,'CN1',NULL,NULL,NULL,3)
insert #charge_log_dates values(NULL,'CN2',NULL,NULL,NULL,8)
insert #charge_log_dates values(NULL,'CN3',NULL,NULL,NULL,18)
insert #charge_log_dates values(NULL,NULL,'BT1',NULL,NULL,5)
insert #charge_log_dates values(NULL,NULL,'BT2',NULL,NULL,1)
insert #charge_log_dates values(NULL,NULL,'BT3',NULL,NULL,6)
insert #charge_log_dates values(NULL,NULL,NULL,'BS1',NULL,9)
insert #charge_log_dates values(NULL,NULL,NULL,'BS2',NULL,10)
insert #charge_log_dates values(NULL,NULL,NULL,'BS3',NULL,30)
insert #charge_log_dates values(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'PC1',15)
insert #charge_log_dates values(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'PC2',15)
insert #charge_log_dates values(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'PC3',45)

SELECT * from #charge_log_dates

drop table #charge_log_dates
```

Here is my main table.  Note that this can be very simple with only one slicer selected or very complex.  (I noticed that previously I had some rows with duplicate values when in reality this table is grouped by payor_family, company_name, base_type, base_state, and payor_code so there shouldn't be duplicates).

```
    create table #main (
payor_family varchar(5),
 company_name varchar(5),
 base_type varchar(5), 
base_state varchar(5), 
payor_code varchar(5), 
measure1 int,
measure2 int,
measure3 int
)

insert #main values('PF1',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,45,14,18)
insert #main values('PF2',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,52,34,13)
insert #main values('PF3',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,10,14,12)
select * from #main
truncate table #main

insert #main values(NULL,'CN1',NULL,NULL,NULL,9,9,18)
insert #main values(NULL,'CN2',NULL,NULL,NULL,13,9,18)
select * from #main
truncate table #main

insert #main values('PF1','CN2','BT3','BS3','PC1',41,14,18)
insert #main values('PF2','CN1','BT1','BS3','PC1',42,15,18)
insert #main values('PF3','CN1','BT3','BS3','PC1',43,16,18)
select * from #main
drop table #main
```

This is what I need the output to be.  The hierarchy from highest level to most granular is payor_family, company_name, base_type, base_state, and payor_code.  This means that if only payor_family is selected, this would only show the count from the row containing the matching payor_family.  But since payor_code is most granular then regardless of what they choose for the other slicers, the count should come from the row containing that matching payor_code.

```
payor_family    company_name base_type  base_state  payor_code  measure1    measure2    measure3    ct
PF1 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    45  14  18  5
PF2 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    52  34  13  10
PF3 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10  14  14  25
NULL    CN1 NULL    NULL    NULL    9   9   18  3
NULL    CN2 NULL    NULL    NULL    13  9   18  8
PF1 CN2 BT3 BS3 PC1 41  14  18  15
PF2 CN2 BT1 BS3 PC1 42  15  18  15
PF3 CN2 BT3 BS3 PC1 43  16  18  15
```

Comment: You gave us the lookup table definition, but not the main query.

Comment: You're saying that you have 5 measures but there's really just one measure doing a distinct count and then one dimension with 5 members: payor_family, company_name, base_type, base_state, payor_code. Is that correct?

Comment: sorry guys, I just now saw your comments.  I have updated my question.

Comment: @salvationishere can you post what you would expect your query to return?

Comment: OK, I just added the expected output

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by doing this in PowerPivot instead.  Thanks for the help.